# multipass a source code to cpp

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor

basically, i'm trying to pass source code twice to gcc's cpp, then directly to gcc's c compiler.

as to why, i believe there are just things that can never be made inline within a macro.

here's an example:

```
/* say i want to make an inline definition that can be inserted to any other macros */
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEF_X                 #define X           22

int main(void)
{
    DEF_X
    printf("%u", X);

    return 1;
}
```

then simply compile:
`gcc $MY_DIR/test_multi_pass.c -o $MY_DIR/test.exe`

of course, this won't work as when you compile it (whether in gcc or not) it gets preprocessed, then directly passed to the compiler (at least officially):

```
    # 1 "d:/Projects/Research/tests/test_multi_pass.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "d:/Projects/Research/tests/test_multi_pass.c"
# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 1 3
# 19 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 3
# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 1 3
# 32 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 3
# 33 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 3
# 20 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 2 3
# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stddef.h" 1 3 4
# 213 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stddef.h" 3 4
typedef unsigned int size_t;
# 325 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stddef.h" 3 4
typedef short unsigned int wchar_t;
# 354 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stddef.h" 3 4
typedef short unsigned int wint_t;
# 27 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 2 3

# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stdarg.h" 1 3 4
# 40 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stdarg.h" 3 4
typedef __builtin_va_list __gnuc_va_list;
# 29 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 2 3
# 129 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 3

ETC_ETC_ETC_IGNORED_FOR_BREVITY_BUT_LOTS_OF_DECLARATIONS

int main(void)
{
    #define X 22
    printf("%u", X);

    return 1;
}
```

now focus on the very bottom of preprocessed file above.

purely speaking, as far as the c compiler is concerned, that "#define X 22" is not valid syntax and any compiler would probably say that there is a stray "#".

so i try a few tricks:

`cpp /$MY_DIR/test_multi_pass.c | cpp`

and the output is:

```
    # 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "d:/Projects/Research/tests/test_multi_pass.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "d:/Projects/Research/tests/test_multi_pass.c"
# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 1 3
# 19 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 3
# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 1 3
# 32 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 3
# 33 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 3
# 20 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 2 3
# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stddef.h" 1 3 4
# 213 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stddef.h" 3 4
typedef unsigned int size_t;
# 325 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stddef.h" 3 4
typedef short unsigned int wchar_t;
# 354 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stddef.h" 3 4
typedef short unsigned int wint_t;
# 27 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 2 3

# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stdarg.h" 1 3 4
# 40 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/stdarg.h" 3 4
typedef __builtin_va_list __gnuc_va_list;
# 29 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 2 3
# 129 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 3

ETC_ETC_ETC_IGNORED_FOR_BREVITY_BUT_LOTS_OF_DECLARATIONS

int main(void)
{

    printf("%u", 22);
    return 1;
}
```

now it's done exactly what we wanted it to do and defined X as 22. this is not exactly how i intend to use in my codebase (and i would be coupling this with #undef, etc), but illustrates the attempt quite clearly.

then i tried:

`gcc -o $MY_DIR/test.exe < cpp /$MY_DIR/test_multi_pass.c | cpp`

i know that in GCC, after initiating the compilation, it is preprocessed by the cpp, then the c compiler syntactically parses the code (to turn i into abstract syntax tree) and along then *quietly* calls the preprocessor again for all the assembly naming (for the linker) and whatnot.

therefore, at least in gcc, a code is twice preprocessed. so there *might be* a chance that a previous file is again in the same format as the next iteration of the preprocessing (hopefully, if it doesn't introduce a lot more extra code that breaks the code further more preprocessing in the future).

so *perhaps* we can preprocess it 4 times (because we preprocess it twice beforehand). hence the hack above.

but what it gives out:

```
sh: cpp: No such file or directory
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"
```

now, is this a fundamental mistake of the cpp not being able to preprocess it 4 times or did i just enter the wrong CLI command??

Comment: *"i believe there are just things that can never be made inline within a macro."* - I would love to see an example of that. I think that you are operating under one or more misunderstandings/incorrect assumptions.

Comment: ^ oh there are things that would surprise you that can be done with inline macros. foreaches, loops, control structures, even recursions. the only thing that i can't defeat, though, is trying to suppress the immediate substitution of a previously defined macro being passed to a function-like macro, and having to senselessly declare too many other macros just to make recursion and comparison work.

Comment: If you need this kind of functionality, you should really consider using a different language as your metalanguage. Try Python or Tcl or something like that. I'm also pretty sure what you're doing is undefined behaviour even if it does appear to work. Macros aren't supposed to generate directives, even for a second pass.

Comment: As for suppressing expansion and making recursion work, just use a library someone's made for you like Boost or Order. These allow for very flexible metaprogramming, and the extra definitions aren't visibly polluting your program, so who cares.

Comment: @AmnatHeer: The error message clearly says that `cpp` doesn't exist and that the process which is complaining about that is `sh`. And that's completely predictable because `< cpp` tells the shell (`sh`) to redirect the standard input of `gcc` to the file `cpp` in the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

GCC only preprocesses your source code once.  If it invokes the preprocessor additional times later in the build process, that's irrelevant, because what it's preprocessing at that stage is not your source code; it's generated assembly code or something.

If you want the effect of running the preprocessor twice on your source code before the actual compilation, you can run the preprocessor once manually, then run GCC normally on the output (which will perform another preprocessor pass automatically).  For example:

```
cpp foo.cpp.in -o foo.cpp
gcc -c foo.cpp
```

However, this double-preprocessing is a rather awkward solution to an unclear problem.  There's probably a better way to accomplish whatever it is that you're actually trying to accomplish.

---

BTW, the reason your command

```
gcc -o $MY_DIR/test.exe < cpp /$MY_DIR/test_multi_pass.c | cpp
```

doesn't work is that you're feeding the *standard output stream* of `gcc` into `cpp`.  You're saying "compile my program, and run `cpp` on any messages that the compiler prints to the screen."  Putting `| cpp` at the end of any command means to preprocess its output, not its input.

Comment: The reason the `gcc` command doesn't work is that there is no file named `cpp` in the current working directory, just as the error message says. I think the intention was something like `gcc -o $MY_DIR/test.exe < <(cpp $MY_DIR/test_multi_pass.c | cpp)` (although that won't work either without a `-x' command line option.)

Comment: @rici, well, that's *another* reason it doesn't work.  :-)  I was just looking at the `| cpp` at the end, which won't do what the OP wanted.

Comment: Yeah, the other point is that gcc prints error messages to stderr, not stdout. So the stdout redirect to cpp is empty -- and will be empty even if there were error messages or warnings -- explaining the three lines you see from cpp.

Comment: oh, yeah, last night i also tried "gcc -o $MY_DIR/test.exe < cpp $MY_DIR/test_multi_pass.c" it says "sh: cpp: No such file or directory"

Comment: also i was hoping that there was a single line command that can do that... my memory of how to write bash scripts is quite blurry now (last time i did it 5-6 years ago) so i wasn`t even too sure if a single line command would do it.