# simple script or commands to *substitute* stray "\\n" with "\n"

Tags: c, regex, perl, c-preprocessor

alright, i understand that the title of this topic sounds a bit gibberish... so i'll try to explain it as clearly as i can...

this is related to this previous post (an approach that's been verified to work):
[multipass a source code to cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336905/multipass-a-source-code-to-cpp)

-- which basically asks the cpp to preprocess the code once before starting the gcc compile build process

take the previous post's sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEF_X   #define X           22

int main(void)
{
    DEF_X
    printf("%u", X);

    return 1;
}
```

now, to be able to freely insert the DEF_X anywhere, we need to add a newline

this doesn't work:

```
#define DEF_X                    \
                #define X    22
```

this still doesn't work, but is more likely to:

```
#define DEF_X   \n                    \
                #define X    22
```

if we get the latter above to work, thanks to C's free form syntax and constant string multiline concatenation, it works anywhere as far as C/C++ is concerned:

```
"literal_str0" DEF_X "literal_str1"
```

now when cpp preprocesses this:

```
# 1 "d:/Projects/Research/tests/test.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "d:/Projects/Research/test/test.c"
# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 1 3
# 19 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 3
# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 1 3
# 32 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 3=
# 33 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 3
# 20 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/stdio.h" 2 3

ETC_ETC_ETC_IGNORED_FOR_BREVITY_BUT_LOTS_OF_DECLARATIONS


int main(void)
{
    \n #define X 22
    printf("%u", X);

    return 1;
}
```

we have a stray \n in our preprocessed file. so now the problem is to get rid of it....

now, the unix system commands aren't really my strongest suit. i've compiled dozens of packages in linux and written simple bash scripts that simply enter multiline commands (so i don't have to type them every time or keep pressing the up arrow and choose the correct command successions). so i don`t know the finer points of stream piping and their arguments.

having said that, i tried these commands:

```
cpp $MY_DIR/test.c | perl -p -e 's/\\n/\n/g' > $MY_DIR/test0.c
gcc $MY_DIR/test0.c -o test.exe
```

it works, it removes that stray \n.

ohh, as to using perl rather than sed, i'm just more familiar with perl's variant to regex... it's more consistent in my eyes.

anyways, this has the nasty side effect of eating up any \n in the file (even in string literals)... so i need a script or a series of commands to:

remove a \n if:

1. if it is not inside a quote -- so this won't be modified: "hell0_there\n"
2. not passed to a function call (inside the argument list)

   - this is safe as one can never pass a single \n, which is neither a keyword nor an identifier.
   - if i need to "stringify" an expression with \n, i can simply call a function macro QUOTE_VAR(token). so that encapsulates all instances that \n would have to be treated as a string.

this should cover all cases that \n should be substituted... at least for my own coding conventions.

really, i would do this if i could manage it on my own... but my skills in regex is extremely lacking, only using it in for simple substitutions.

Comment: `DEF_X` -> `#ifdef DEF_X   #define X           22 #endif` or `perl -p -e 's/DEF_X/\#include X 22/g'`

Comment: wrapping it in #ifdef? i've come across that in my search, but i don't think even that behavior is standard in GCC. works for a wide version of GCC, though.

Comment: `#ifdef` is a part of C and C++ standards.

Comment: no, i meant, in gcc's preprocessor all tokens are separated by space character no matter what whitespace or how many whitespace there is between each term in the **original** text. do the test or ask around to confirm this. #ifdef/#endif is like a whole block which is probably why the people of gcc decided that that is the only case where they would use a newline instead of a space, for readability

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to replace `\n` if it occurs in the beginning of line.

The following command should do the work:

```
sed -e 's/\s*\\n/\n/g'
```

or occurs before `#`

```
sed -e 's/\\n\s*#/\n#/g'
```

or you can reverse the order of preprocessing and substitute `DEF_X` with your own tool before C preprocessor.

Comment: "occurs before #" -- that's brilliant! i was so fixated in my own conventions i forgot to consider other solutions... ughh... "requirements 1 and 2"...

Comment: i really should be more familiar with unix commands so i can think within that framework...

Comment: If I answered your question, feel free to accept my answer.

Comment: oh, wait... i checked again and seems that one can't always have a situation where, when one has to substitute a \n and there is a proceeding directive after it... though if there was a "#dummy" directive that leaves an empty space, i guess that would cover all cases.

Comment: "#dummy" doesn't contain `\n`. It isn't worth it to create tool for all cases, unless you do tool for external usage. But in that case, usage of your own preprocessor isn't justified.

Comment: #define FUNC_1(arg) #undef arg \ func(arg) "func(arg)" ends up in the same line as #undef, making: #undef arg func(arg) which as far as the preprocessor is concerned, you are passing too many tokens if one has a #dummy directive that erases itself and retains all other token to it's right: #dummy func(arg) turns to: func(arg)

Comment: How is that related to the answer?