# Preprocessor flags suitable for not tokenizing but still do concatenation

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I have inherited some PCL (Patran Command Language) code that is preprocessed with a C preprocessor to enable use of macros etc. This code has a number of features that do not work for modern preprocessors such as cpp. Currently I'm using `gcc -E` or `cpp` with version 11.3.0.

For example, one issue is caused by `//' being the concatenate operator in PCL, but being recognised as a comment by cpp:

```
$ A.pcc

#define FUNC(X) ui_write(X)
string variable
FUNC("text "//variable//" more text")
```

The required result is

```
string variable
ui_write("text "//variable//" more text")
```

I can preprocess this successfully with the command

```
cpp -traditional A.pcc
```

where `-traditional` says to use old style cpp which doesn't tokenize, so the comment symbol is not an issue. If not using this flag, the preprocessor fails to match the argument `X` within `FUNC(X)` and errors as it ends the token search at the comment.

In the same file (and many others) token concatenation / token pasting is also being used:

```
$ B.pcc

#define CAT(I,J) command ## I ## J ## s()

CAT(1,2)
```

The required result is

```
command12s()
```

However by using the `-traditional` flag, token concatenation is turned off, so the result is

```
command ## 1 ## 2 ## s()
```

Which isn't valid PCL.

Any suggestions for appropriate flags? These two issues occur in the same files so I am unable to compile different files with different flags. My current best idea is to use sed to replace the comments with other characters, preprocess, then put them back in.

Edit:
I've found a cpp only solution via this answer ([multipass a source code to cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336905/multipass-a-source-code-to-cpp?rq=2)), so the line for me would be

```
cpp -traditional file.pcc | cpp -C
```

where the `-C` flag says to keep comments. I'll have to add a macro to each file so the token concatenation doesn't occur in the first pass

```
#define DEF_CAT #define CAT(I,J) command ## I ## J ## ()
DEF_CAT
```

Comment: Compiler and preprocessor flags are vendor specific. Please [edit] your question and specify what compiler preprocessor you are using, and which version.

Comment: You state that same file has mixed code, so presumably this has worked before. What changed that it doesn't work now?

Comment: What happened to `string variable` and empty line in the first example?

Comment: @user694733 I inherited the code and a C compiler executable however the executable has permission issues on my system and can't be run. I also don't know the program or version of the executable and it was put in place 14 years ago so I don't think I can follow it up. Talking to the last person to build it, the response is 'works for me' so I need to figure out how to build it again. I've got it working now using my edit approach but still interested in better solutions

Comment: sorry @KamilCuk sloppiness on my behalf

Comment: Do your best to get rid of as much use of the preprocessor as possible - that should simplify your problem.

Comment: It would be nice longer term @JesperJuhl but currently there are ~150 macros defined and ~300 includes so it would take a bit of time to reduce the need for the preprocessor.

Comment: Good catch @KamilCuk, another victim of my simplifications for SO.

Comment: You could try to compile with `-std=c89` or `-ansi` (I believe they are the same) to switch compiler into old standard mode which should disable line comments. (I haven't tested this myself.)

Comment: Yeh I tried that @user694733 but if it ignores comments then the macro FUNC(X) doesn't match the X correctly, as it never finds the closing bracket (as it is within the comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocess the `//` to something `cpp` ignores, and then preprocess it back. The following `/tmp/mycpp`:

```
#!/bin/bash
uuid=06ae45e2-dd08-40db-abeb-1089e89e638f
sed "s@//@$uuid@g" "$@" | cpp -P -xc - | sed "s@$uuid@//@g"
```

The following shell transcript presents execution:

```
$ in='
#define FUNC(X) ui_write(X)
string variable
FUNC("text "//variable//" more text")

#define CAT(I,J) command ## I ## J()
CAT(1,2)
'
$ /tmp/mycpp <<<"$in"
string variable                                                                                                                 
ui_write("text "//variable//" more text")
command12()
```